# Getting value from submitted form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with 2 buttons (`type="submit"`). Each of them has different value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myform').submit(function() {
    var _att = $(this).attr("value");
    if (_att == "insert") {
      //do insert here ....
    }
    if (_att == "update") {
      //do update here ....
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" /><br>
  <button type="submit" value="insert">Insert Button</button>
  <button type="submit" value="update">Update Button</button>
</form>
```

My question is, how to get value from clicked button in the submitted form?
I tried by trying to get `attr("value")` but the return value is `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle the `click` event on `[type="submit"]` to get their `attr("value")`, *i.e.*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[type="submit"]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let value = $(this).attr("value");
    console.log(value);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" /><br>
  <button type="submit" value="insert">Insert Button</button>
  <button type="submit" value="update">Update Button</button>
</form>
```

*N.B.* Remember to prevent their default behavior (with [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)).

Comment: I just knew '[type="submit"]' can be used efficiently.

Comment: @Daleman `Type=submit` is not usually required in a button. An input is ideal to have a type=submit.

Comment: Its not ideal to use `[type="submit"]` as a click handler as this will cause issue if you have other [type="submit"] on the same HTML page. Its not ideal at all. This is not recemended to be done. Not sure how you suggested this way. Thanks

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I just followed your suggestion anyway....

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this easily by using a unique class `.submit-button` on your button

I have also added `preventDefault` function which will ensure that your page is not refreshing on form submit button clicked and check for all the validations - if any accordingly.

Run snippet to see it working below.

Working Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xo3pkqf9/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myform button").click(function() {
    //Check which button was clicked
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "insert") {
      //Form Submits
      alert("Insert Clicked - Form will submit")
      $("#myform").submit();
    }
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "update") {
    alert("Update Clicked - Form will submit")
    //Form Submits
    $("#myform").submit();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" required/><br>
  <button type="submit" value="insert">Insert Button</button>
  <button type="submit" value="update">Update Button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: By using your code, why I got " undefined" as return value ?

Comment: @Daleman Its should work just fine just like its working above in the snippet. Copy the exact code and html to see if that helps.

Comment: It should work fine. Your jsfiddle code also works fine. My code always return 'undefined'

Comment: @Daleman Try now I have simplified and updated the answer. I have added a unique class to a button and that way you can get the value of a button. Let me know

Comment: I think, I prefer using your code `$('#myform').submit(function (e) {})` because it will check all elements in the form not just even click button and I also have validation javascript. If I use `('.submit-button')`, it just focus on the button and ignoring the javascript validation form. But, again, in my code, why does it just return 'undefined' ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216509/discussion-between-alwayshelping-and-daleman).

Comment: @Daleman See the updated answer. It checking on click which button was clicked as well its submitting the form using `.submit` - Hope this helps.